# Looping though elements in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way I can loop though multiple elements with number based names, changing their properties?

**Example:**

Here are an example set of elements on my form:

```
Element1
Element2
Element3
Element4
Element5
```

This is the kind of thing i was thinking of:

```
For i = 1 To 5
    Element + i .BackColor = Color.Maroon 
Next
```

This is just because I have a large number of elements, which i would like to change the properties of during the application running.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: What control is element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, replace `Me.Controls` with another control collection if that is not the right one.

Label example:

```
For i = 1 To 5
  Dim lb = TryCast(GameInterface.Controls("Element" & i.ToString), Label)
  If lb IsNot Nothing Then lb.BackColor = Color.Maroon 
Next
```

Comment: i'm relatively new to vb.net, so all i can say is that these elements are labels. so this should work??

Comment: You tell me, are they labels or other controls?

Comment: they are labels, sorry the question mark was misleading

Comment: then if they exist in the form's control collection then that will work - did you try it?

Comment: then your controls do not live in the form's collection or the names are not as you told me, are the name "Element1", etc...?

Comment: yes the name is correct, how can i check if they live in the forms collection?

Comment: ooh actually it is in a panel

Comment: Then use that for the control collection - see answer

Answer (score 0):

If it is for labels on form then try this:
replace parent with Parent control

```
Private Sub SetControls()
        Dim xControl As Control
        For Each xControl parent.Controls
            If (TypeOf xControl Is Label ) Then
                xControl.backcolor= Color.Maroon
            End If
        Next xControl
End Sub
```